# How to unifdef recursively

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How can I use unifdef on a directory recursively.
The following command removes code around DEFINE_NAME on a given file.
I would like to remove code from all files under a directory.

```
unifdef -UDEFINE_NAME filename
```

Comment: Did you try `unifdef -UDEFINE_NAME directory/*` ?

Comment: how abut `unifdefall` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got GNU findutils, you can use `find` to execute commands with found files whose name ends with `.c` or `.h`:

```
% find -name '*.[ch]' -exec unifdef -m -UDEFINE_NAME '{}' ';'
```

`exec` gets a command that will have a filename substituted, `{}` is the place where a found filename is substituted, and `;` ends the command.

On the other hand if you use `zsh` as your shell, you can use a recursive glob:

```
% unifdef -m -UDEFINE_NAME **/*.[ch]
```

Notice that you need `-m` to actually modify the file in place.